Steiner trees and their topologies
As I could understand, the Steiner topology is obtained by the structure of a non-degenerate minimum Steiner tree which solves the Steiner tree problem. That means, the corresponding Steiner tree has the minimum length tree that connects given terminals and added Steiner vertices. In a book, it is mentioned that a relatively minimal tree can be achieved by locating the Steiner vertices in such a way that the total length of the geometric network is minimised. What I could not understand here is how the total length is minimised further in the Steiner tree (geometric network) which gave the minimum length.
